# How can I find the number of EC2 instances?

Tags: python, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In shell script or Python, how can I find out how many EC2 instances are running and the count of the instances in each AWS region?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --output text | wc -l
```

If you wish to do it for a non-default region:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --region ap-southeast-2 --output text | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you first install the AWS CLI. Then take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html which will show you how to get a list of running instances. You could write a bash script that invokes this describe-instances command and uses the filters available.

Comment: i'm getting the list of instances but i want the count of instances running.i'm new shellscript so i'm not able to write command if you know could you help me with the command

Comment: You should look into using pipes and probably wc -l is what you will eventually want to use. I would google bash parsing json (or whatever format you are having the details returned as).

Comment: for i in `aws ec2 describe-regions | jq --raw-output '.Regions[] | .RegionName'` ; do echo "*** $i ***" ; aws ec2 describe-instances --region "$i" | jq --raw-output ".Reservations[].Instances[] | .InstanceType" ; done for getting list of instances in the region i have used the above command how can i modify it to get the count of instances

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the configservice as follows:

```
% aws configservice get-discovered-resource-counts --region eu-west-1 --profile MyProfile
{
    "totalDiscoveredResources": 828,
    "resourceCounts": [
         ...ommitted for brevity's sake....
        {
            "resourceType": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "count": 94
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface",
            "count": 60
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "count": 56
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "AWS::EC2::Volume",
            "count": 55
        },
        {
            "resourceType": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "count": 44
        },
        ...ommitted for brevity's sake....
```

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/configservice/index.html